# Transform tool does not rotate according to centroid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rotate

I am using `Adobe Illustrator` to rotate a triangular object.

I found that using the `Effect -> Distort and Transform -> Transform` rotation works different than a standard rotation made possible during scaling.

To 'illustrate' this problem, I attached a picture below to show how the standard rotation transforms my triangle.

[image: perfect triangle in middle of perfect circle]

Notice how all sides of the triangle touch the circle, since it is a perfect triangle. Now when I standard rotate it, it still does this.

[image: perfect rotated triangle in middle of perfect circle]

This makes perfect sense. Now when I use the `Effect -> Distort and Transform -> Transform` tool, the rotation does something (to me) unexpected.

[image: imperfect rotated triangle in middle of perfect circle]

How come that the latter transform tool does not rotate according to the centroid? How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illustrator will follow the center of the **bounding box** when trying to rotate. The center of the bounding box, is not the same as the centroid.

*Bounding Box* center point:

[image: bounding box center point]

*Centroid*:

[image: centroid]

---

To fix this, group them together for the transform (that's how I do it) and you can un-group them afterwards.

They will then follow the bounding box of the *circle* not the triangle.

---

See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91467/63979) for more info.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right, I just found out myself that I could group it and then get it done; so I was about to post the answer and then found out about your answer. Perfect, and you added an explanation that I did not understand before. Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: @mroWsymaS my pleasure! I'm about to add some images for a more visual explanation too.